# Expo EAS Build Failed on Windows: The "Run fastlane" step failed with an unknown error. Multiple Commands Produce Error in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, expo, eas

I am trying to run an EAS development build from my PC but the build keeps failing with the error: Build failed: The "Run fastlane" step failed with an unknown error. Refer to "Xcode Logs" below for additional, more detailed logs.

On inspection of the faslane logs, I see that the error is:  Multiple commands produce '/Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appname-ecbncfeqsmojcvdraulchiitzzhd/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/appname/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/AccessibilityResources.bundle'

Here is the rest of the fastlane logs following this error:

```
duplicate output file '/Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appname-ecbncfeqsmojcvdraulchiitzzhd/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/appname/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/AccessibilityResources.bundle/en.lproj' on task: CpResource /Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appname-ecbncfeqsmojcvdraulchiitzzhd/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/appname/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/AccessibilityResources.bundle/en.lproj /Users/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/react-native/React/AccessibilityResources/en.lproj (in target 'React-Core-AccessibilityResources' from project 'Pods')

    duplicate output file '/Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appname-ecbncfeqsmojcvdraulchiitzzhd/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/appname/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/AccessibilityResources.bundle' on task: MkDir /Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appname-ecbncfeqsmojcvdraulchiitzzhd/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/appname/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/AccessibilityResources.bundle (in target 'React-Core-AccessibilityResources' from project 'Pods')

    duplicate output file '' on task: MkDir /Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appname-ecbncfeqsmojcvdraulchiitzzhd/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/appname/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/AccessibilityResources.bundle (in target 'React-Core-AccessibilityResources' from project 'Pods')

    duplicate output file '/Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appname-ecbncfeqsmojcvdraulchiitzzhd/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/appname/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/AccessibilityResources.bundle/Info.plist' on task: ProcessInfoPlistFile /Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appname-ecbncfeqsmojcvdraulchiitzzhd/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/appname/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/AccessibilityResources.bundle/Info.plist /Users/expo/workingdir/build/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/React-Core/ResourceBundle-AccessibilityResources-React-Core-Info.plist (in target 'React-Core-AccessibilityResources' from project 'Pods')

    duplicate output file '' on task: RegisterExecutionPolicyException /Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appname-ecbncfeqsmojcvdraulchiitzzhd/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/appname/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/AccessibilityResources.bundle (in target 'React-Core-AccessibilityResources' from project 'Pods')

    duplicate output file '' on task: SetMode u+w,go-w,a+rX /Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appname-ecbncfeqsmojcvdraulchiitzzhd/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/appname/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/AccessibilityResources.bundle (in target 'React-Core-AccessibilityResources' from project 'Pods')

    duplicate output file '' on task: SetOwnerAndGroup expo:staff /Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appname-ecbncfeqsmojcvdraulchiitzzhd/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/appname/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/AccessibilityResources.bundle (in target 'React-Core-AccessibilityResources' from project 'Pods')

    duplicate output file '' on task: SetOwnerAndGroup expo:staff /Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appname-ecbncfeqsmojcvdraulchiitzzhd/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/appname/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/AccessibilityResources.bundle (in target 'React-Core-AccessibilityResources' from project 'Pods')

    duplicate output file '' on task: Touch /Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appname-ecbncfeqsmojcvdraulchiitzzhd/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/appname/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/AccessibilityResources.bundle (in target 'React-Core-AccessibilityResources' from project 'Pods')

    unexpected mutating task ('SetOwnerAndGroup expo:staff /Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appname-ecbncfeqsmojcvdraulchiitzzhd/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/appname/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/AccessibilityResources.bundle') with no relation to prior mutator ('SetOwnerAndGroup expo:staff /Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appname-ecbncfeqsmojcvdraulchiitzzhd/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/appname/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/AccessibilityResources.bundle') (in target 'React-Core-60309c9c-AccessibilityResources' from project 'Pods')

    unexpected mutating task ('SetMode u+w,go-w,a+rX /Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appname-ecbncfeqsmojcvdraulchiitzzhd/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/appname/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/AccessibilityResources.bundle') with no relation to prior mutator ('SetMode u+w,go-w,a+rX /Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appname-ecbncfeqsmojcvdraulchiitzzhd/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/appname/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/AccessibilityResources.bundle') (in target 'React-Core-60309c9c-AccessibilityResources' from project 'Pods')

    Run script build phase 'Start Packager' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'appname' from project 'appname')

    Run script build phase 'Bundle React Native code and images' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'appname' from project 'appname')

    Run script build phase '[CP-User] Generate app.config for prebuilt Constants.manifest' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'EXConstants' from project 'Pods')

▸ ** ARCHIVE FAILED **

** ARCHIVE FAILED **

Exit status: 65
```

I have looked at similar issues and updated all dependencies, inspected all my config files, i've checked the recommended guides on fastlane's codesigning, but couldn't find a solution that addresses this specific issue.

Has anyone faced a similar problem or has any suggestions on how to resolve this?

Thank you for any assistance!